# How to upload Large file on server

Tags: php, ios

I am a PHP Developer i have made a Web Service for uploading file from Ios End.But the problem is when i upload a 15MB file from server end the file was successfully uploaded i have also done the following setting in php.ini.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 50M
//PHP script to upload a file
<?php
  $filename = $_FILES["userfiles"]["name"];
  $destination = $_FILES["userfiles"]["tmp_name"];
  $file = time() . $filename;
  $result = move_uploaded_file($destination, "upload/" . $file);

?>
```

But When Ios Developer try to upload a 15MB file on server it gives following error Error `Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 The request timed out`

For this i have increase the execution time also `set_time_limit(0)` in Webservice.But i am not getting any success.Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can show uploading function?

Comment: Means PHP script to upload a file..?

Comment: Not full, part code for upload file (get name and move from `/tmp/` folder to `/your_upload/` folder ) sorry for my English.

Comment: You can use var_dump for check error in uploading `var_dump($_FILES);die;` before this string `$filename = $_FILES['userfiles']['name']`

Comment: Just try your API using PHP cURL to send a file, if that file is successfully uploaded then there is a problem with iOS developer.

Comment: In ios after some time it shows request time out error our Webservice is not calling because connection has been terminated.So we can do any thing from server end.

Answer (score 0):

we have php function ini_set that is use to override default php.ini setting

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','50M');
ini_set('post_max_size','50M');
```

Please put that code on top of the file or at the top of the function

thanks

Comment: Its not working again the same result has been show at IOS end request time out.

Comment: This can happen if your network configuration changes while the simulator is running. Please reboot the simulator runtime (eg: quit/relaunch the iOS Simulator.app) and that will likely fix your problem.      

and please look the doc related to that error. 


https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/index.html

Comment: I think there is no error in you code. that is some network issue.